# Error : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CALL" Errors: check compiler log

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting this error in Oracle SQL Developer. Here's the code.

```
drop table PRODUCTDESC;
drop table PRODUCT;

create TABLE PRODUCT(
 ProductId Number,
 ProductName VARCHAR2(30),
 CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY(ProductId)
);


create Table PRODUCTDESC(
ProductId Number,
ProductDescription varchar2(60),
Number_of_sales Number(9),
CONSTRAINT PRODUCTDESC_fk FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES PRODUCT (ProductId)ON DELETE CASCADE  
);


INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (11,'HL Road Frame-Black,58');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (12,'HL Road Frame-RED,58');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES (13,'Sport-100 Helmet,Red');



INSERT INTO PRODUCTDESC VALUES (11,'Replacement Mountain Wheel
for Entry level rider' , 800);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTDESC VALUES (12,'Sturdy alloy features a quick-release hub' , 900);
INSERT INTO PRODUCTDESC VALUES (13,'Aerodynamic rims for smooth riding' , 600);


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetProducDesc
IS
    CURSOR cur IS
        SELECT P.ProductId, P.ProductName, PD.ProductDescription
        FROM PRODUCTDESC PD
        LEFT JOIN PRODUCT P
        ON PD.ProductId = P.ProductId;
    rec cur%rowtype;

BEGIN
    FOR rec in cur LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(rec.ProductId || ' ' || rec.ProductName || ' ' || rec.ProductDescription);
    END LOOP;
END;

 Call GetProducDesc();
```

All data is being inserted, Procedure is being compiled but then I get the above error. I believe there is something wrong with my call statement but I cant find what

Comment: Looks like you are missing a `/` at the end of the `GetProducDesc` procedure. This is needed in scripts to tell the interpreter where the PL/SQL section ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

```
BEGIN
   GetProducDesc;
END;
/
```

or in SQL PLus

```
exec GetProducDesc;
```